# How to set weights of the batch normalization layer?

Tags: keras, batch-normalization

How do I set weights of the batch normalization layer of Keras?

I am bit confused by the documentation

weights: Initialization weights. List of 2 Numpy arrays, with shapes: [(input_shape,), (input_shape,)] Note that the order of this list is [gamma, beta, mean, std]

Do we need all four [gamma, beta, mean, std]? Is there a way to set weights using only [gamma, beta]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need all four values. Recollect what batch normalization does. Its goal is to normalize (i.e. mean = 0 and standard deviation = 1) inputs coming into each layer. To this end, you need `(mean, std)`. Thus a normalized activation can be viewed as an input to a sub-network which does a linear transformation:

```
y = gamma*x_norm + beta
```

`(gamma, beta)` are very important since they complement `(mean,std)` in the sense that `(gamma, beta)` help get the original activations back from the normalized ones. If you don't do this or change any one parameter without considering the others, you risk changing the semantic meaning of the activations. These original activations can now be processed with your next layer. This process is repeated for all layers.

**Edit:**

On the other hand, I think it would be worth trying to first compute the mean and std on a large number of images and take input that as your mean and std. Take care that the images that you are computing mean and std on, come from the same distribution as your training data. I think this should work as batch normalization usually has two modes for computing mean, one is running average maintained over batches and the other is global mean (at least in Caffe, see [here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1BatchNormLayer.html)).

Comment: Thanks, but my question was more specific to keras batch normalization layer, which I had indicated only through the tag. Found out that I can use `K.set_value` to achieve this.

Comment: @Prasanna can you please tell me what you did? What is `K`? I am trying to set values for gamma, beta, running_mean & running_variance individually.

Comment: @Chhaganlaal `K` is the Keras backend. I think it is `from keras import backend as K`.